# How do I approach this problem. Involving getting the area between curves.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, area

2. Find the area of the region bounded by the curves $y = cos(x)$ and 
   $y =cos^2(x)$ where $ x = 0 $ and $x = π.$

The formula for this is $$\int_{a}^{b} (y_{top} - y_{bot})dx$$

What confuses me is the $x = 0$, and $x = \pi$ are given, but that doesn't tell me the $y$ values.

maybe

$$\int_{0}^{\pi} [\cos^2 (x) - \cos(x)] dx$$

$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \left[\frac{1}{2} (1+\cos(2x)) - \cos(x)\right] dx$$

$$= \big(\frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{4}\sin(2x) - \sin(x)\big)\bigg|_{0}^{\pi} = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

---

EDIT:

$$\int_{0}^{\pi} |cos^2 (x) - cos(x)| dx = -\int_{0}^{\pi/2} (cos^2 (x) - cos(x))dx + \int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} (cos^2 (x) - cos(x)) dx $$

Since it is negative from 0 to pi/2, and positive from pi to pi/2.

This gives me -3/2 as the answer

Comment: The $y_{top}$ refers to the one function of the two that is "on top". Similarly $y_{bot}$ refers to the bottom function. As for the limits of integration, you are taking an integral with respect to $x$ as can be seen by the $dx$ in the integral, thus, the limits of integration should be in terms of $x$.

Comment: oh so would my answer be right except i go from 0 to pi?

Comment: Close, the answer provided by Guacho Perez is what you're after

Comment: Tried both, gave same answer. How am I wrong?

Comment: The correct answer is $2$. http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+0+to+pi+of+%7Ccos%5E2%28x%29-cos%28x%29%7C&x=0&y=0

Comment: I don't know what im doing wrong could you look at the edit?

Comment: $-[(\pi/4-1)-(0)] +[(\pi/2)-(\pi/4-1)] = 1-\pi/4+\pi/2+1-\pi/4 = 2$

Comment: oh whoops i forgot about the 2x. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find $$\int_0^{\pi} |\cos(x)-\cos ^2(x)|dx$$, to do this, just find where $\cos(x)-\cos ^2(x)=0$ for $x\in [0,\pi]$. The solutions to that equation should break the interval into smaller intervals. From each of these intervals take an $x$ and plug it into $\cos(x)-\cos ^2(x)$, if the result is negative, then $y_{\text{top}}=\cos ^2(x)$. Then use your formula using the endpoints of the corresponding interval as your limits of integration.

Answer (score 2):

For $\,x\in[0,\pi/2]\,$ we have $\,\cos(x)\in[0,1]\,$, hence $\,\cos^2(x)\leq\cos(x)\,$, which means that

$$y_{top}=\cos(x),\quad y_{bot}=\cos^2(x)$$

For $\,x\in[\pi/2,\pi]\,$ we have $\,\cos(x)\in[-1,0]\,$, hence $\,\cos^2(x)\geq\cos(x)\,$, and this gives

$$y_{top}=\cos^2(x),\quad y_{bot}=\cos(x)$$

As a result, the integral you are trying to find is

$$\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\cos(x)-\cos^2(x)\,dx\,+\,\int_{\frac\pi2}^\pi\cos^2(x)-\cos(x)\,dx$$